# Updating a field based on other fields being changed

Tags: c#, winforms, c#-4.0

If I have several fields containing a currency value and a total field, how do I keep the total up-to-date when any value is changed?

I know that I can use events like `ActiveChanged` or `Changed` against individual controls but this becomes laborious when you have a lot of fields and also creates a lot of identical methods which seems inefficient to me.

I know that I can also use a button but this requires more input from the user. I'd like it to be somewhat automated so that the total can be observed as values are entered, or at least when switching to the next field.

Currently it's going to be a lot of code like below.

```
private void field1_Changed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            calculate();
        }

private void field2_Changed(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            calculate();
        }
```

Comment: Are the fields on the same class? If so you could use an expression-bodied member. E.g. `public decimal Total => field1 + field2;`

Comment: Also, you can have events have the same event handler. As in, you don't have to have a separate event handlers `field1_Changed` and `field2_Changed` if they perform the same action, just one and then set the changed event for each of the fields to that one event.

Comment: I have just tried that and it doesn't seem to work. I'm not defining a class here as I'm working within an SDK for another application

Comment: If you are wanting to update your form when a value changes, you'll also probably want to implement [INotifyPropertyChanged](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx) even if using the expression-body.

Comment: It looks like my controls don't implement that interface and the version of C# doesn't support expression-body.

Comment: Tag your C# version in the question. Are you unable to modify parts of your codebase?

Comment: It's C#4.0 or 5.0 (.NET 4.0). I'm not able to change all code but I can bring in my own controls if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If exactly same code needs to be executed then you can create only one event handler and point all them to same event handler

Go to form.designer.cs and change event handlers. For very basic example, 2 text box pointing to same event handlers

```
this.textBox1.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ValueChanged);

this.textBox2.TextChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.ValueChanged);
```

In form.cs

```
private void ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            this.label1.Text = (int.Parse(this.textBox2.Text) 
                               + int.Parse(this.textBox1.Text))
                               .ToString();
 }
```

Comment: Thanks - If I get time I'll try this out over the weekend